# How to insert select and join method in query using when method?

Tags: mysql, join, select, laravel-5

I am using when method for search filtering with this code:

```
 $newitem = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->when(request('umur'), function($query){
                    $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);
                })
                ->when(request('negeri_lahir'), function($query){
                    $query->where('NegeriID', request('negeri_lahir'));
                })
                ->when(request('kategori'), function($query){
                    $query->where('CategoryID', request('kategori'));
                })
                ->when(request('pangkat'), function($query){
                    $query->where('OperasiID', request('pangkat'));
                })
                ->get();
```

But I need to insert join and select method to get the categoryname and operasiname. but when I insert it to the code, the query error appear.

```
 ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=', 'categories.categoryid')
 ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
 ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname')
```

How to use join and select method in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for conditional filtering. This might help you.

```
$query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
        ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=','categories.categoryid')
        ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
        ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname');

        if(request('umur')) {
            $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);  
        }

        if(request('negeri_lahir')) {
            $query->where('NegeriID', request('negeri_lahir'));
        }

        if(request('kategori')) {
            $query->where('CategoryID', request('kategori'));
        }

        if(request('pangkat')) {
            $query->where('OperasiID', request('pangkat'));
        }

    $newitem = $query->get();
```

Comment: I already tried and find out..there is error of "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'CategoryID' " when I select the filter for category and operasi. If I select nothing, or select negeri filter, it works fine. like it clash with sql stament select and if condition.

Comment: @joun I guess ```"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation``` error is because of ambiguous column names. You have to specify table_name with column name in where condition like ```$query->where('categories.categoryid', request('kategori'));``` or ```$query->where('itemregistrations.categoryid', request('kategori'));``` likewise.